# PHP: Edit link in content

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I am trying to add a string to the end of any link in content, my trying this code:

```
   add_filter('the_content', 'crawl_content');
function crawl_content( $text ) {
    $search = '/href="(.*?)"/s';
    preg_match_all( $search, $text, $matches);
    for ($a = 0; $a < count($matches[0]); $a++)    {
        $new = "href=\"" . $matches[1][$a] . "/?=dddd\" class=\"newsLink\"";
        $text = preg_replace('%' . $matches[0][$a] . '%', $new, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

The problem is :

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'd' in functions.php on line 112
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you want help, you need to be a bit clearer.  What text is being passed in to your filter? What text is being returned? How do you want the text being returned to be different (or, what would it be if it were "Correct"?  **Be specific**.  The details matter!

Comment: @cale_b i edit my post

Comment: What is the content of `$text`? Which line is `112`?

Comment: You have not been specific enough.  What is the text you are passing to the function? What do you want added? Where?  Which line of your code is 112?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have the character used as delimiter (ie `%`) present in the string.

You could escape it with [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
// all domains to exclude, separated by |
$domains_to_exclude = 'kam.com|kam2.com';

for ($a = 0; $a < count($matches[0]); $a++) {
    if (preg_match('~'.$domains_to_exclude.'~i', $matches[1][$a]) ) continue;

    $new = "href=\"" . $matches[1][$a] . "/?=dddd\" class=\"newsLink\"";
    $text = preg_replace('%' . preg_quote($matches[0][$a], '%') . '%', $new, $text);
}
```

Comment: This is my guess to.  Since the matches can contain any number of characters, including "special" regex characters.  Didn't know about preg_quote, great solution!

Comment: how can exclude some domain from it ?

Comment: @wpPicture: The simplest way is to test the array `$matches[0][$a]` at the begining of the loop.

Comment: thank you, but i add domain like (kam.com) but not work, are you mean add like (http://kam.com) ?

Comment: @Toto remember ,,, my domain have some time string variable like
`kam.com/media/kamdd.jpg`
some time like 
`kam.com/sound/dddd.mp3`

Comment: @wpPicture:see my edit. But, if you add new request, please, ask a new question with all details and testcases

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, a regular expression needs to be enclosed within a pair of [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character; /, #, ~ are the most commonly used ones.

```
function crawl_content($text)
{
    $search = '/href="(.*?)"/s';
    preg_match_all($search, $text, $matches);
    for ($a = 0; $a < count($matches[0]); $a++) {
        $new  = sprintf('href="%s/?=dddd" class="newsLink"',$matches[1][$a]);
        $text = preg_replace('~' . $matches[0][$a] . '~', $new, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: OP uses `%` as delimiter, your suggestion doesn't answer the question.

Comment: please test url  <a href="https://3v4l.org/%ef">text</a> to delimiter %